# C# VSTO Office add-in: “FindRibbons” task failed unexpectedly

Tags: c#, vsto

Every time I compile the project, I get this error. My  AssemblyInfo.cs file does not have the attributes `ExcelLocale1033` or `SecurityTransparent`. There is no `VisualStudio` folder in `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft`.

```
The "FindRibbons" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'ProjectName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'ProjectName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

Server stack trace: 
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed. It's because of a new project that I added to the VSTO solution. This other project's output type (right click project > Properties) used to be `Windows Application`. I changed that to `Class Library` and deleted `Program.cs` which contained this code:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
```

The error never showed up again.